# Clone a remote maven repository to a local repository in artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am trying to clone a remote repository https://maven.forgerock.org/repo/forgerock-virtual to a local maven repository set up in my JFrog Artifactory. The only settings to import is to import from filesystem. I am not sure how to clone the entire remote repository to a local repository such as this?

Also if I clone the remote repo to filesystem first and then import to local repository it will consume a lot of time and it won't be efficient enough.

Comment: To clone, you should first download all the artifacts and cache them under the remote cache repository and then move/copy to the local repository. Other than this approach I see no other way to do so.

Comment: @Muhammed How do I cache all artifacts from a remote repository? Also how can I copy from a remote repo to local repo?

Comment: you should first create a maven remote repository pointing to https://maven.forgerock.org/repo/forgerock-virtual and then there will be to repos created. Suppose you gave the name for the remote repo as forgerock then there will be another repo called forgerock-cache available. Once forgerock remote repo is created use "http://art_url/artifactory/forgerock" and download all the artifacts. The downloaded ones will be available under forgerock-cache repo and from there you can copy to the local repo by right clicking on forgerock-cache and select copy and in target repo give the local repo

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a remote repository is not a good idea at all. You already have a binary repository manager set up. Configure in your Artifactory:

- a 'public' group of repositories
- a proxy of Maven Central like `central`
- include the 'central' proxy in `public` group
- add the proxies to any other external repositories to the public group like the `central` above, any time needed
  Set up your Maven's settings.xml to mirror the Maven Central and redirect to the `public` group in your Artifactory.

For example, the settings.xml could contain (the example is with Nexus):

```xml
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>public-local</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>Let the default Maven Central repository is resolved in the local Nexus' public repository</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

This allows your Artifactory to download and cache locally all and only the artifacts you actually use. No need to download them manually.